# CLI command to Get aws sdk for java version

Tags: java, aws-java-sdk

How can I get the aws java sdk version? I know of java -version but it's showing jdk version.

I already tried java -version but it shows jdk version

NA

I expect the sdk version

Comment: jdk means Java development kit, which is java's name for its sdk (software development kit)

Comment: Hi JoSSte, Thanks for the response. Do you know of specific command to get the version?

Answer (score 2):

Please see [VersionInfoUtils](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/VersionInfoUtils.html) method `getVersion`

Javadoc of method :

> > Returns the current platform for the AWS SDK in which this class is running. Version information is obtained from from the versionInfo.properties file which the AWS Java SDK build process generates.

Comment: Hi Shashwat. Thanks for the quick response. Do you know of linux command on how to get it?

Comment: This link you can follow to get AWS in linux https://christierney.com/2019/01/22/getting-aws-java-sdk-2-0/

Comment: If you have aws cli installed then you can use `$ aws --version`  but that will give the version of aws cli. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html